# Outgoing mail doesn't work

Tags: thunderbird

Recently started migrating to Ubuntu from windows where my email services worked fine. I set up my mail utility using Thunderbird. It receives  mail ok (POP3) but won't send. I get the following error message: The message could not be sent because the connection to SMTP server smtp.zoominternet.net ( my service provider) timed out.

Comment: There is no general answer I am afraid, there must be a mistake or an error in the account settings. Did you use Thunderbird on Windows as well?

Comment: Thx for responding. I used Microsoft Access in windows. Since I can receive, I assume my password settings are correct. The Outgoing field address(smtp server) looks ok. There seems to be very little I can change in Thunderbird (security?)...

Comment: That Pop works does not mean smtp works as well, and there is a lot more than the password that can go wrong, depending on your required server settings

Comment: Changed port from 1 to 2. That didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditto on Jacob's response. Many times as simple as the port setting as incoming and outgoing should be different.

Check the configuration requirements at your service provider carefully.

Also, if you have it working on windows, look at the configuration there 'very carefully' to replicate on Linux.

Comment: In order to look into the Windows settings must reload XP. Did this a moth ago; and must set email,etc...

Answer (score 0):

Checked with the service provider. The output port needed to be 25. It was set to 1 by default. Made the change and everything works fine. Thx for your input.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, how did you exactly 'make the change'?

Comment: I activated Thunderbird and selected edit > Account Settings... browsed around  (clicked on a few tabs) and found the outgoing mail settings. Changed the output port number from 1 to 25. Thunderbird is my mail utility. Yours might be something else.

Comment: Somehow my answer and the question got disconnected. The question was: my outgoing mail wasn't working.